# Confusion about prioritizing functional groups in case of poly functional organic compounds

Tags: organic-chemistry, acid-base, nomenclature

According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sulfonic_acid#Properties),
sulfonic acid $(\ce{-SO3H})$ is comparatively stronger than carboxylic acid $(\ce{-COOH})$.

Then why is sulfonic acid lower in priority than carboxylic acid (while naming poly functional organic compounds) in [this priority chart](http://www.organicmystery.com/Tables/PriorityTable.php)? Even my textbook prioritizes $(\ce{-COOH})$ over $(\ce{-SO3H})$.

Or is the strength not the only factor while assigning priority?

Correct me if I'm wrong or missing something. I'm currently learning about IUPAC nomenclature.

Comment: Acidity has no relation to nomenclature.

Comment: Then why does -cooh get priority over -so3h?

Comment: Because IUPAC [published a book](http://dx.doi.org/10.1039/9781849733069) that says so. There is not much more to it than that...

Comment: Did they do it just as such without any justification?

Comment: Yes, pretty much.

Comment: see [Is the precedence of functional groups used in IUPAC naming arbitrary?](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/140997/103369)