# Is the precedence of functional groups used in IUPAC naming arbitrary?

Tags: organic-chemistry, nomenclature

There seems to be a priority order that has to be followed while naming an organic compound with more than one functional group , according to IUPAC rules. I want to know if there is a basis on which this priority list has been made, or is it just arbitrarily ordered.

I have tried to connect the dots but failed, first i thought it may be the s-character of the atom which is in direct link with the parent chain, doesn't work out, then about their atomic weights, that too, failed.

Is there some order among this chaos?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generally, languages are older than their dictionaries. Therefore, the first dictionaries are usually *descriptive;* i.e. they describe the language. Later there may also be *prescriptive* dictionaries; i.e. they are more concerned about a standard language and prescribe the proper usage and spelling of words.

The same principle applies to chemical nomenclature. The first chemical names are older than any systematic nomenclature rules. The first nomenclature rules tried to describe the already existing chemical names, as explained for example in an early version of the rules used in *Chemical Abstracts* [[1](https://doi.org/10.1021/ja02253a011)]:

> We have not tried to invent a new system. Our aim has been to follow existing usage as far as it could be made fairly consistent, choosing what appeared to us good practices and rejecting bad, and introducing new features only when some very positive advantage was to be gained.

In particular, this descriptive approach also applies to the seniority order of functional groups:

> With compounds of mixed function there must be a definite understanding as to which is the chief one for purposes of naming. After considerable experimenting we have adopted the following order of precedence, based on existing usage:
> (“Onium” compounds), acid (carboxylic first), acid halide, amide, imide, aldehyde nitrile, ketone, alcohol, phenol, mercaptan, amine, imine, ether, sulfide (and sulfoxide and sulfone).

Note that this list is already very similar to the current IUPAC recommendations.

Remarkably, however, the International Union of Chemistry at the meeting held in Liége (1930) could not decide to include this seniority order in their reform of the nomenclature of organic chemistry yet [[2](https://doi.org/10.1021/ja01337a001)] (The Liége rules were the predecessor of the IUPAC nomenclature of organic chemistry.):

> The Committee intended at one time to establish an *order of precedence of functions* (to determine which should be the principal function in a compound containing two or more different functions), but later gave up the idea.

Nevertheless, the 1965 IUPAC rules included such a list [[3](https://doi.org/10.1351/pac196511010001)]:

> 1. ’Onium and similar cations
> 2. Acids: in the order $\ce{COOH}$, $\ce{C(=O)OOH}$, then successively their $\ce{S}$ and $\ce{Se}$ derivatives, followd by sulfonic, sulfinic acids, etc.
> 3. Derivatives of acids: in the order anhydrides, esters, acyl halides, amides, hydrazides, imides, amidines, etc.
> 4. Nitriles (cyanides), then isocyanides
> 5. Aldehydes, then successively their $\ce{S}$ and $\ce{Se}$ analogues; then their derivatives
> 6. Ketones, then their analogues and derivatives, in the same order as for aldehydes
> 7. Alcohols, then phenols; then $\ce{S}$ and $\ce{Se}$ analogues of alcohols; then esters of alcohols with inorganic acids*; then similar derivatives of phenols in the same order
> 8. Hydroperoxides
> 9. Amines; then imines, hydrazines, etc.
> 10. Ethers; then successively their $\ce{S}$ and $\ce{Se}$ analogues
> 11. Peroxides

---

1. [Patterson, A. M.; Curran, C. E. A System of Organic Nomenclature. *J. Am. Chem. Soc.* **1917,** *39* (8), 1623–1638.](https://doi.org/10.1021/ja02253a011)
2. [Patterson, A. M. Definitive Report of the Commission on the Reform of the Nomenclature of Organic Chemistry Translation with Comments. *J. Am. Chem. Soc.* **1933,** *55* (10), 3905–3925.](https://doi.org/10.1021/ja01337a001)
3. [Nomenclature of Organic Chemistry (Definitive Rules for Section C. Characteristic Groups Containing Carbon, Hydrogen, Oxygen, Nitrogen, Halogen, Sulfur, Selenium, and/or Tellurium). *Pure Appl. Chem.* **1965,** *11* (1–2), 1–260.](https://doi.org/10.1351/pac196511010001)

Comment: This clears up everything ! I learnt much more than what i asked for, and although the comment instructions tell me to not write thanks, I can't help myself , so , a sincere thanks to you!

Comment: In the second quotation, there is a line which says **"After considerable experimenting"** , does this refer to experimentation as in with the substances, or with the existing literature and its usage?